# Nuxt Failed to execute ‘appendChild’ on ‘Node’ when trying to get window size

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

The problem is that the project must be transferred to Nuxt and some of the code does not work. Namely, the size of the screen must perform actions with the text. Since Nuxt is an SSR, the code cannot be executed on the server side because it does not know the size of the window.

Can I somehow fulfill this idea so that everything works?
I have a project with nuxt and i18n

```
[nuxt] Error while initializing app DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
    at Object.Je [as appendChild]
```

this my component vue
This code is an example of what causes an error.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div>           
            <h2 class="subtitle" v-html="filterHeadSlogan"></h2>            
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'testapp',
    data() {
      return {
        filterHeadSlogan: '',
        windowWidth: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getWindowWidth(event) {
        this.windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
        var str = "<i>HELLO WORLD</i>"
        if (this.windowWidth >= 960) {
          this.filterHeadSlogan = str
        } else {
          this.filterHeadSlogan = str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
        //Init
        this.getWindowWidth()
      })
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: This error happens when there mismatch in data on client vs server. There should be more detail when u run it in dev mode ( e.g. warning in console )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nuxt js "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method" on mobile view port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124873/nuxt-js-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-this-node-type-does-not-supp)

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred because there was no data in the variable. The village appeared, but there was no data and there was a conflict. I created asyncData

```
  async asyncData(){
        return {
          headSlogan: ""
        }
      },
```

Full code

```
<template>
    <div class="westartslogan">
        <div class="head-slogan">
            <h2 v-html="headSlogan"></h2>
        </div>
        <h3>{{$t('page.home.wellcom_block_subtitle_left')}}</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><i class="icon"></i>
                <div v-html="$t('page.home.wellcom_block_option_1_left')"></div></li>
            <li><i class="icon"></i>
                <div v-html="$t('page.home.wellcom_block_option_2_left')"></div></li>
            <li><i class="icon"></i>
                <div v-html="$t('page.home.wellcom_block_option_3_left')"></div></li>
            <li><i class="icon"></i>
                <div v-html="$t('page.home.wellcom_block_option_4_left')"></div></li>
            <li><i class="icon"></i>
                <div v-html="$t('page.home.wellcom_block_option_5_left')"></div></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="startcalc-btn button-container">
            <nuxt-link   :to="getLocalizedRoute({ name: 'calculator' })"  class="uk-button uk-button-default">{{
                $t('page.home.wellcom_button_calculator') }}
            </nuxt-link >
        </div>
        <div class="ourproject-btn uk-hidden@s">
            <div class="button-container">
                <nuxt-link :to="getLocalizedRoute({ name: 'portfolio' })" class="uk-button uk-button-default">
                   {{ $t('page.home.wellcom_button_portfolio') }}
                </nuxt-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      async asyncData(){
        return {
          headSlogan: ""
        }
      },
      name: 'we_can',
      data () {
        return {
          filterHeadSlogan: '',
          headSlogan:  this.$i18n.t('page.home.wellcom_block_title_left'),
          windowWidth: 0
        }
      },
     methods: {
       getWindowWidth (event) {
         this.windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
         if (this.windowWidth >= 960) {
           this.headSlogan = this.headSlogan
         } else {
           var str = this.headSlogan
           this.headSlogan = str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
         }
       }
     },
    mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
          //Init
          this.getWindowWidth()
      })
    }

  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

I was dealing with the same problem.

Do these steps:

1. Run your project (`yarn start`).
2. Open http://localhost:3000/ in Chrome.
3. In Chrome devtools clear site data in application tab.
4. Hard reload the page.

Comment: I had this problem on production only and these steps actually corrected it on my computer...