# nuxt js "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method" on mobile view port

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

found this error when trying to run my `nuxtjs` app with `vuetify` on mobile viewport, but everything runs well on desktop viewport.

error on local machine [image : error on local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJbZJ.png) :

`The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

error on server with ubuntu and nginx running my nuxtjs app with `pm2` using 
`yarn build` then `pm2 start yarn -- start`
[image : error on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3FmZ.png)

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.`

both errors occur in the same scenario.

when i run it on desktop viewport, then switch to mobile viewport (without reloading the page) it runs well. but if i reload it on mobile viewport, these error occur.

not sure which page I should share because this error occur on all pages even on the nuxt+vuetify default homepage.

currently the same error also occur on desktop viewport, but it's fixed by wrapping my component inside `<client-only></client-only>`,and error gone from desktop viewport but still occur on mobile viewport.

Answer (score 26):

Check if you are using `v-if` directive

Try changing it to `v-show` because `v-show` renders the HTML and sets display property to true or false, while `v-if` doesn't render (real [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)).

In my case, I had `v-if` on some nodes in my template and replacing it with `v-show` kept the element in the DOM and helped missing node errors like this.

Comment: thanks a lot. worked for me. my problem was having some `v-if` directives without `v-else` in `v-app-bar`. also I had to change `v-navigation-drawer` component and added `app` directive in that.

Comment: oh wow, that worked for me - I had a v-if on the top level element of a component, and was doing a static generate, and when I loaded that component dynamically via a GET param I got the error - v-show fixed it!!

Comment: This helped me out. I had a v-if on a parent div with childs that were rendered using v-for. In SSR it worked but on static mode it failed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

In my case, this error occurred when I wanted to use vuex persistent libraries.

[This](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1552#issuecomment-393236698) answer is helped me a lot, but I didn't know which elements cause the error, so I ended up wrapping my whole app in it and it just worked!

```
// ~/layouts/default.vue
<template>
  <v-app v-if="!loading">
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    loading: true
  }),
  created() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      this.loading = false
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `asyncData` put the section of template that render it in `<client-only>` tag, If you add the code people can better help you

Comment: just realize i miss something in my question, i already wrap my component inside `<client-only>' tag, and it's fix the errors in desktop viewport. not sure which template code i have to share since the error occur in all page, i'm still trying to figure out which component couses this error

Answer (score 3):

So I spent days on trying to figure out why it was happening on one of my project. And even if can't give you a solution I would tell you that you can narrow down to where it comes from.

What you have to do is to encapsulate your whole app with `<client-only></client-only>` to ensure it's an SSR problem (Which is almost for sure the case).

Then piece by piece you encapsulate only part of your project.
For exemple only the `<header>`. That way, you'll be able to understand where it comes from and apply a proper solution.

Just in case, in my specific case it was due to `vuex-persistdata` and I finished just encapsulating this part since I wasn't needing it in SSR.

Comment: This one worked for me. I've added `<client-only></client-only>` this in layout as my app doesn't use SSR. Thanks Baldráni

Answer (score 2):

you need client only tags

```
<template>
  <div id="container">
     <client-only>
        <Components>
     </client-only>
  <div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had like this problem. The problem was caused by incorrect HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was caused by this part:

```
<Card
  v-for="(obj, index) in myArray"
  :key="index"
  :obj="obj"
/>
```

Then I fixed this issue by changing the `key`, like:

```
<Card
  v-for="(obj, index) in myArray"
  :key="`${obj.title}-${index}`"
  :obj="obj"
/>
```

I think the problem was due to the fact that my template had few `v-for`s with `:key="index"` (so few components had the same index) as a result it could lead to some Nuxt's internal collision.

For some reason this issue appears just in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why you can see this. One is also because you have `/` sign at the end of the input field (hydration problem).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using Bootstrap Vue and some tags were wrongly closed, I had the following bad formatted tags in a lot of files inside my project:

```
<b-icon icon="icon" />

And 

<b-img src="https://url.com"/>
```

And I needed to change them to:

```
<b-icon icon="icon"></b-icon>

And 

<b-img src="https://url.com"></b-img>
```

Please check that your tags are closed as the documentation says, I can also recommend you to use [html-validator](https://html-validator.nuxtjs.org/), which helped me a lot to understand some common Hydration errors caused by bad formatted or deprecated code.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
<NuxtLink to="/services-details">
   <a>Chemistry Tutor Jobs</a>
</NuxtLink>
```

then changed to

```
<NuxtLink to="/services-details">
       <div>Chemistry Tutor Jobs</div>
    </NuxtLink>
```

and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For my case (ssr), i just move the code from "beforeMount" hook to "mounted" and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem occurred after logging in. It was because I had this in my Html:

```
<p>{{ $auth.user.email }}</p>
```

The solution was to control the email value in a variable, not using this directly in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use `<client-only>` for plugins that have to work at client like : sliders select data pickers time pickers or anything that doesnt need to SSR SEO
in local host go to console tab and set pointer to know where is the element make error

i had same problems that was for Carousel that i use , i write it in the `<client-only>`

and sometime its for useing `v-if` use `v-show` instead

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was caused by multiple-nested ul.li's. Not sure what was going on, but I kept the inner ul.li and changed the outside one to `<div>` tags, and all is now fixed!