# NuxtJS: DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.

I get this error the first time I open the site in my browser. NuxtJS. If after refreshing the page, there is no more error. The error occurs only if the user is authorized with nuxt-auth module, unauthorized user does not get this error.

If you open the site in devmode, the first time you open the site redirects stop working and in the console

> The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside `<p>`, or missing `<tbody>`. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

And this error occurs even on empty page if I remove all elements and components.

I disabled all modules and components from the page, deleted all the HTML, and still get this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nuxt js "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method" on mobile view port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124873/nuxt-js-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-this-node-type-does-not-supp)

Comment: @Samball This is not the same issue