# DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, nuxt.js

im using nuxt 2 and when i start my project in my local there is no error and this issue only occurs when the frontend is in production mode, in dev mode everything works.
i dont get error in my laptop , just when im using mobile
does anyone know how to fix it

i got some warning in my local is this related to each other ?
err
`[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

i tried this but not working [nuxt js "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method" on mobile view port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124873/nuxt-js-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-this-node-type-does-not-supp)

Comment: Without seeing any code, only a psychic will be able to help.

Comment: bro If I had known I would have done it
; i found the answer but thanks